# Publish website without project name on github

Tags: github, github-pages

I used Github Pages to upload web site:
https://username.github.io/projectname

How can I upload web site in root URL? So, it will be:
https://username.github.io/

For example:
https://webcommunityukie.github.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a repository named `<put your username here>.github.io` and push your static files to the `gh-pages` branch of that repo. [Here](http://github.com/webcommunityukie/webcommunityukie.github.io) you can see that `webcommunityukie` has a repo named `webcommunityukie.github.io` which therefore gets published on `webcommunityukie.github.io`.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a repo with name is `username.github.io` and you can serve your static web on your repo (https://pages.github.com/)